# App store rejects Unity game over info.plist permissions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am a small time indie dev, working on publishing my first game for iOS. Everything has worked so far, but when I try to submit my app, it gets rejected and I get an email that states that the problem is:

"This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data."

My app does not use the camera in any way, but okay - so I edited my info.plist to include an NSCameraUsageDescription. Even after adding it and trying several different values I repeatedly get the same rejection error.

I am using Xcode version 8, and Unity version 5.4.1f1.

Comment: I've had the same problem and solved it adding "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" to the info.plist and an empty string as description.

Comment: I think it relates to ReplayKit which availables in Unity version 5.4. Try to open Classes/Unity/CameraCapture.mm in generated Xcode project, go to the first line and replace "#if !UNITY_TVOS" and with "#if 0". This will effectively remove camera capture code and you should pass automatic submission check.